# Finding a combination of numbers of size N that sum up to a given number

Tags: java, algorithm

Given the number C and a number N. I want to find N numbers that sum up to C and the difference between the highest and the lowest of these number should not be more than one.
For example:

Given these -> (C = 26, N = 7) --  I need an algorithm that would find these -> [4 4 4 4 4 3 3]

C = 11, N = 5 - [3 2 2 2 2]

C = 17, N = 4 - [5 4 4 4]

C = 10, N = 3 - [4 3 3]

C = 5, N = 2  - [3 2]

Edit: Had a mistake in the examples.

I did this:

```
    //N and C are declared above.
    int[] numbers = new int[N];
    int lowBound = C / N;
    int Modulo = C % N;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = lowBound;
    }
    while(Modulo > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

            if(Modulo < 1) break;
            numbers[i]++;
            Modulo--;
        }
     }
```

Also i am sorry.

I was just looking for a headstart, I am quite new here.

Comment: Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I answered it, but I think, the comment is valid, how much have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea where to even begin. I have little to no knowledge of algorithms. And a friend needs this for some project at school.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code service. Try something, and share your attempts.

Comment: This is the formula you can go by: `x + 1 + x * (N - 1) = C`. Use a while loop, start x at 1 until you find the value for `x` that gives `C`. Actually on second thought, this wouldn't work because it's too greedy on `x`. On third thought, it would work if you are not greedy with `x`, but also involve `x-1` in the calculation, so `x * a + (x - 1) * b = C where (a + b = N)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a dump of a school assignment without any effort whatsoever in trying to solve it, even stated in the comments by the author. StackOverflow is not a free code service.

Comment: just a thought - start with k=round_up(C/N). then keep subtracting C by k until the result of that equals to (k-1)*(N-i), where i is the number of subtractions made so far.

Comment: @james I think you are really close to the solution, but instead of rounding up, round down. Then `k * N` will be less than or equal to `C`. If less than, then the difference between `k * N` and C has to be less than N, therefore keep adding `1` to each `k` (remember you have N of them) until of the sum of the remaining `k`s plus the ones you added a `1` to are equal to C!

Comment: In other words, `let k = floor(C / N)` and `rk = floor(C / N) + 1`, then the answer is you need to this many `rk` -> `P` and this many `k` -> `N - P` where `k` is the smaller number and `rk` is the larger, and `P` is `C - (k * N)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From the comment section to the answer box*

Turns out you don't need a loop for this, just math.

```
public class SolveCombination {
    public static List<Integer> solve(int c, int n) {
        int k = c / n;
        int rk = k + 1;
        int p = (c - (k * n));

        return Stream.concat(Stream.generate(() -> rk).limit(p), 
                             Stream.generate(() -> k).limit(n - p))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

#### Sample runs with jshell

```
jshell> solve(26, 7)
$7 ==> [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3]

jshell> solve(17, 4)
$8 ==> [5, 4, 4, 4]

jshell> solve(10, 3)
$9 ==> [4, 3, 3]

jshell> solve(5, 2)
$10 ==> [3, 2]

jshell> solve(11, 5)
$11 ==> [3, 2, 2, 2, 2]

jshell> solve(0, 5)
$12 ==> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

jshell> solve(1, 5)
$13 ==> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

jshell> solve(0, 0)
|  java.lang.ArithmeticException thrown: / by zero
|        at solve (#6:2)
|        at (#14:1)

jshell>
```